# Change undline icon items of tabs in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how to change the underline of tabs selected icon in flutter , the one int he picture and thank you [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `TabBarTheme` data in your `Theme` that you use in `MaterialApp` (or wrap that widget with your own theme and change `TabBarTheme` there) there are multiple attributes but one in particular that you can change is the indicator decorator:

[image]

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBarTheme-class.html